# Custom radio button with a checked indicator on the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Can someone tell me how can I create a radioGroup with radio buttons that will have the look like on the image:

[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/network_creation_radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/network_creation_private"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/lock"
                android:text="Private"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView_LightGrey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Anyone can join" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/dark_gray" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/network_creation_public"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/unlock"
                android:text="Public"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView_LightGrey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Join via a suggest from existing\nnetwork members" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio Button Selector xml

`res/drawable/radio_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_unselected" android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Now add <strike>`android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"`</strike> `android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_selector"` to every radio button tag.

Comment: here he is asking about radio button should be right side of the text. but your answer is about custom radio buttons.

Comment: he could add `android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_selector"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of radio button you can use Checked Text View [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) and [here](http://puneetaggarwal.in/android/checkedtextview/) is the example but in this you have to handle the checked states like radio group. Means if one is checked you have to make another one is unchecked.